# BlueJ Error: Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String (Ticket Machine Simulation)

Tags: java, oop, bluej

I'm very new to java and after trying the best I can to create a ticket machine in bluej, I literally have no idea what to do.

```
 public class CarParkTicketMachine
{
    private double RunningBalance;
    private double CurrentBalance;
    private String CarReg;
    private static double MinTicketCharge = 0.7;

    //Constructor
    public CarParkTicketMachine()
    {
        RunningBalance = 0;
        CurrentBalance = 0;
    }

    //Try and request a ticket
    public void RequestTick()
    {
        if(Validate())
        {
            //Create a ticket for the customer
            CarParkTicket ticket = new CarParkTicket (CarReg, CurrentBalance);
            //keep a running total
            RunningBalance += CurrentBalance;
            //clear the customer's balance
            CurrentBalance = 0;
            //print ticket for the customer
            ticket.PrintTicket();
        }
    }

    //Perform check to ensure we can purchase a ticket
    private boolean Validate()
    {
        boolean valid = false;

        //Check that the user has entered their car registration
        if(!(CarReg == null || CarReg.isEmpty())) //must NOT be null
        {
            //Check that the user has entered enough money
            if(CurrentBalance >= MinTicketCharge)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You have not entered enough money");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your car registration");
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class CarParkTicket
{
    //Customer's Car Registration
    private String CarRegistration; 
   //Cost of the ticket
   private double charge;

   public CarParkTicket (String CarReg, double charge)
   {
       CarRegistration = CarReg;
       double Charge = charge;
    }

    public void PrintTicket()
    {
        System.out.println("*****************");
        System.out.println("Your Ticket");
        System.out.println("Registration:" + CarRegistration);
        System.out.println("Cost: £" + charge );
        System.out.println("*****************");
    }
}

public class Coin
{
    //property to hold the value of the coin
    private double Value;

    //Constructor
    public Coin(double value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    //accessor
    public double GetValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

My three classes compile without any problems however when I create a new object of the 'CarParkTicketMachine' and try to enter a method call for setting the car registration or inserting a coin I get a 'Error: cannot find symbol - variable.

I feel that the problem lies in this part, but because I'm incredibly new to java/bluej I really have no idea how to solve this issue:

```
private Boolean Validate()
    {
        boolean valid = false;

        //Check that the user has entered their car registration
        if(CarReg == (" "))
        {
            //Check that the user has entered enough money
            if(CurrentBalance >= MinTicketCharge)
            {
                valid = true;
            }
            else
            {System.out.println("You have not entered enough money");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter your car registration");
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

Comment: In java strings are objects so when you compare strings you should call the .equals() method or .compare() method.

Comment: `CarReg == (" ")` This is not valid code.

Comment: I have 3 infos for you: 1. [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html); 2. `CarReg == (" ")` is not correct, use `CarReg.equals(" ")` to compare `String` types; 3. If you have a question about an error/exception, then post the whole error/exception and mark the line there it occurs. Edit: 4th info: `!CarReg.Trim().Equals("")` this will never compile ([Read the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)), change it to `!CarReg.trim().isEmpty()`.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for replying, however now when I create a new object for 'CarParkTicketMachine' and right click it I only have the option of 'void RequestTick()' and not any of the other ones that I had before e.g.SetCarRegistration. As I said before I'm very new to java and so I don't know what information to provide you with to help me so anything pointing me in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question?

Comment: @Bailey The reason why you have only one method left is, that you've deleted the other public methods. No wonder they are gone.

Comment: @Tom Updated: The only difference in code was the changes suggested by DatLuckey

Comment: @Bailey You've deleted `SetCarReg` and `InsertCoin`, that is why you can only select the remaining public method `RequestTick`.

Comment: @Tom So I have re-added SetCarReg and InsertCoin where they was originally with the amendments made to the 'private boolean Validate()' part and entering the registration works however when I try and enter a value into 'void InsertCoin' I get an "Error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Coin".

Comment: @Bailey That method requires a `Coint` instance as the argument. So you can't call it like `InsertCoin(1);`. `1` is an `int`, not a `Coin`.

Comment: @Tom I don't want to make it seem like you're doing the work for me but how would I go about implementing that into what I already have coded?

Comment: @Bailey either `InsertCoin(new Coin(1D));` or change the parameter of `InsertCoin` to `int`.

Comment: @Tom I think you're going to need to hold my hand here. Regardless of what I change it to I get an 'illegal start of type'public void InsertCoin (new Coin(1D)); 
    {
        CurrentBalance+= coin.GetValue();
    }

Comment: You should not change the method declaration, you should call that method like I wrote ;).

Comment: @Tom It's working however it does not display the price of the ticket which should be £0.70 *****************
Your Ticket
Registration:qweqrtw
Cost: £0.0
*****************

Comment: @Bailey: `double Charge = charge;` should be `Charge = charge;` (in `public CarParkTicket (String CarReg, double charge)`)

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your help! Any advice on how I can learn more about java? I've began reading the objects first with java book which seems like it will be quite a worthwhile read but any other books/online tutorial suggestions would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for the Validate():
Note that you are trying to check if the user has entered " " and then check for the cash entered. 
But you need to be sure the user has NOT entered " " (which means he entered a number or a name)

```
private bool Validate()
{

    //Check that the user has entered their car registration
    if(!(CarReg == null || CarReg.isEmpty())) // must NOT be null
    {
        //Check that the user has entered enough money
        if(CurrentBalance >= MinTicketCharge)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("You have not entered enough money");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your car registration");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit: I should tell you that after the "return true", the method stops executing. So when you do not return true (which means the if statement for cash was not true), the method goes to the end where it returns false.

You can make your if statement shorter by using a so called "tenary operator".

This should look like so:

```
return CurrentBalance >= MinTicketCharge ? true : false;
```

You have your if-statement and your return in one line.